# Qt: how to clear the fields of form?

Tags: qt, forms

I have some form with fiels, combos etc. I would like to go over through all the widgets on the form and if for example it's textfield, clear it, something like that:

```
foreach(QObject *child, this->ui->children())
{
    QLineEdit *txtField = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(child);
    if (txtField)
    {
        txtField->clear();
    }
}
```

The problem is the ui object doesn't have such property like children and I don't know how to get the whole collection of children widgets.

Maybe the form object has something like Clear method. It would be the best.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it.

```
foreach(QLineEdit *widget, this->findChildren<QLineEdit*>()) {
    widget->clear();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me, thanks! But I had to remove setupUi code because the form has some strange additional widgets inside. I suppose I don't need it because this method was called before.

Comment: The `setupUi` code shouldn't really be there... It doesn't make much sense to clear form right after initialization - and calling setupUi more than once can probably lead to memory leaks.

Comment: @TomášZato I agree. I'm not sure why I put it there. Maybe to tell that it is needed to be called somewhere before.

Answer (score 2):

How many `QLineEdit`s are we talking about? Unless there's a good reason I would just add a method to the class that has `ui` as a member and do it by hand, like this:

```
void clearform()
{
    this->ui->firstlineedit->clear();
    this->ui->secondlineedit->clear();
    ...
    this->ui->nthlineedit->clear();
}
```

A good reason why you can't do it this way is that the `QLineEdit`s are dynamically added and you don't have them as members. In that case you can call [QObject::children](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#children) on the widget that is the parent of all your `QLineEdit`s, if they share some common name, [QObject::findChildren](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#findChildren) will also work.